# PHP: How to embed image in an excel column generated from PHP?

Tags: php, php4

I am echoing TSV data and turning it into an excel file via header()

This works fine, but 1 of the columns needs to be an image. How can I embed the image as one of the columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, put simply, you can't. A TSV is a plain text (text/plain) file, not an 'Excel file'. An excel file is a binary representation of a spreadsheet, and although Excel can read a TSV and present it as tabular data, it's not this advanced binary form which can contain images.

You would have to create a 'proper' Excel xls file using one of the available libraries. I've used [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) in the past and I think it supports adding images.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any I can install without having access to PHP.INI? Thanks

Comment: Worth trying PHPExcel or the Pear one detailed below. I don't think PHPExcel required any special settings but you'll have to try it to be sure. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is anyway to use TSV data, and get Excel to display an image.

However, I have had success in using [Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer) from PEAR, and it supports inserting images (bitmaps). Also supports nice formatting, etc, etc.

Comment: I looked into that, but you have to have excess to the PHP.INI file which I unfortunately do not.